# Pausing execution in jQuery $.each loop for JSON items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm running into a problem with jQuery, calling remote data via JSOND. I'm wanting to pause execution in between each item in the array within a dataset; I want to pull down the data and then pause for 3 seconds between each item so I can display each item before hiding it and moving on to the next one.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$.getJSON(someURL,function(data) {
   $.each(data.items,function(index,item) {
      setTimeout(function() { alert('found one!'); },3000);
   });
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that the code runs setTimeout() only after 3 seconds, and then fires the alert() dialog for every item in the collection. So visually, it runs through the items so fast, only the last one is ever visible.

Can someone point out where my error is? Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that the each loop happens within milliseconds so basically all the setTimeouts differ by 1-2 milliseconds total.

Try multiplying by the index

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('found one!'); },3000 * index);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's it...to test, I've even hard-coded larger values (like 20 seconds), but it basically flies through the items on one pass, indicating to me that setTimeout never got called. I'm actually doing this to dynamically mark points on a Google Map and re-center the map according to the data in JSON. I can see the items all load, with the last one being visible. Got any ideas? :)

Comment: @Jason: *"Got any ideas?"* Did you try this one from @epascarello? This looks like a correct solution. A `setTimeout` doesn't pause the loop. The loop finishes long before the first `setTimeout` calls its function. So because the starting point for every `setTimeout` is nearly identical, the end point will be as well.

Comment: ah! my bad....i misunderstood. works perfectly. thanks all...you guys (or gals) rock!  :)

Comment: Mark an answer so people help you in the future

Answer (score 0):

Each setTimeout will each fire 3 seconds after you trigger them, not sequentially. If you want them to appear sequentially, you need to increase that timeout each iteration of data.items or trigger the next one after each one fires. Here is a simple re-work.

```
$.getJSON(someURL,function(data) {
   var delay = 0;
   $.each(data.items,function(index,item) {
      setTimeout(function() { alert('found one!'); }, delay += 3000);
   });
});
```

Of course alert will wait for the user to dismiss them, so this example will still look strange as alerts pile up every 3 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

This way alerts the first item, waits 3 seconds, alerts the 2nd item, wait 3 seconds, etc.

```
$.getJSON(someURL,function(json){
  function doSomething(data){
    if(data.length>0){
      var curItem=data[0];
      alert('item: '+data[0]);
      setTimeout(function(){
        doSomething(data.splice(1));
      },3000);
    }
  }
  doSomething(json.items);
});
```